# How to give someone a role with role ID?

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I tried

```
    @bot.command(pass_context=True)
    @commands.has_role(764795150424866836)
    async def removerole(ctx, user: discord.Member, role: 763045556200931348):
        await user.remove_roles(role)
```

But i get an error:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: role is a required argument that is missing.
```

Hopefully you can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `:` in parameters when you specify the `class` of the parameter. If you want to assign a value, you should use `=` like `async def removerole(ctx, user: discord.Member, role=763045556200931348):`. But I think that that's not what you want. You want to remove the role from the user. You can do it by mentioning the role.

```py
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_role(764795150424866836)
async def removerole(ctx, user: discord.Member, role: discord.Role):
    if role in user.roles:
        await user.remove_roles(role)
```

With that, you just have to mention the that you want to remove from the user.

But if you just want to type the role id to remove the role, you can use `guild.get_role(id)`.

```py
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_role(764795150424866836)
async def removerole(ctx, user: discord.Member, role=763045556200931348):
    remove_role = ctx.guild.get_role(role)
    if remove_role in user.roles:
        await user.remove_roles(remove_role)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try to re-write your function as this:

```py
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_role(764795150424866836)
async def removerole(ctx, user: discord.Member, role=763045556200931348):
    role = ctx.guild.get_role(role)
    await user.remove_roles(remove_role)
```

The reason why you were getting that error, is because you were not pre-defining the `role` variable. That is done by doing this: `role=763045556200931348`. Instead, you were defining the type of variable it is (`discord.Member`) by doing this: `role: 763045556200931348`, which is the incorrect implementation of the role variable.

Comment: now im getting the error: discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'id'

Comment: What arguments are you giving the command when you enter it into the Discord chat? Are you mentioning a role when you do it? Or are you just not giving any arguments at all?

Comment: i type in $(my prefix)removerole @user

Comment: Okay, try mentioning a role after you mention the user.

Comment: that works but it isn't wat i want. i want that this command only removes the role with the id i typed in

Comment: Since that works, that means that the issue is from the role that we are pre-defining. I actually will have to think about that for a second.

Comment: take your time i can wait

Comment: I think all you have to do is just get the role now. I'll add it to the function.